# python(numpy) -- another way to produce array (from another array)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i did this code :

```
from scitools.std import *


npoints=10

vectorpoint=array(random.uniform(-1,1,[1,2]))
experiment=array(random.uniform(-1,1,[npoints,2]))
print("vectorpoint=",vectorpoint)
print("experiment=",experiment)
print(vectorpoint.shape)
print(experiment.shape)
```

which works fine.
I wanted to ask if the "experiment" array can be written in another way ,such as for example "experiment=[vectorpoint,npoints]".I want to use the vectorpoint array.

(I don't want to write all over again the "random.uniform(-1,1,[npoints,2])".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `experiment` to be an array with `npoints` lines which are all equal to `vectorpoint`, you can use

```
experiment = vstack([vectorpoint] * npoints)
```

If you want `experiment` to have `npoints` lines independently generated by `random.uniform()`, you have to call the latter function again, since `vectorpoint` only contains the numerical values returned by `random.uniform()` and no information on how it was generated.  If the repetition bothers you, you can move it to a function:

```
def uniform(lines):
    return random.uniform(-1, 1, [lines, 2])
```

(Note that your use of `array` is redundant -- the return value of `random.uniform()` already is an array.)